# Music player with auto library refresh?

Tags: libraries, music-player, shared-library

is there any music player with the ability to auto-refresh it's contents, when a song is added in it's library directory manually?

like, if i add a song on my iTunes library on my Mac OS partition, then the Ubuntu player i'm searching for (which will also has the same directory as a library folder) will automatically have the song that has been added in the player ...

Answer (score 1):

Check out [quodlibet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/) (disclaimer: I'm one of the current devs).

Recent versions come with a *Automatic Library Update* plugin (again, disclaimer...) which does exactly that, using the Python [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) wrappers. It will even update your current view / search results as you add or remove new songs...

You can get the latest stable version thus:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:lazka/ppa
sudo apt-get install quodlibet quodlibet-plugins python-pyinotify
```

Hope that helps.